# Four display images when live USB booting Ubuntu on an iMac

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, mac

Attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an iMac (running Snow Leopard) with a corrupt partition. Goal is to erase the hard disk and install Ubuntu (NOT dual-boot).

Have a bootable USB stick made (using a different machine) according to the instructions at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos. This USB stick has already been used successfully on other machines.

Holding down option while powering up, I can boot to the USB stick. But the display shows four barely legible copies of the screen.

[image: jpeg of the four barely legible copies of the screen]